# How find element thought parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following DOM tree:

```
<div class="row" id="row-1">
   <div class="row-wrapper">
       <div class="cell-1"></div>
       <div class="cell-2"></div>
       <div class="cell-3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="row-2">
   <div class="row-wrapper">
       <div class="cell-1"></div>
       <div class="cell-2"></div>
       <div class="cell-3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Let's say I have reference to cell-1 in row-1:

```
var $cell = $("row-1 .cell-1").first();
```

How could I get reference for the next down cell-1 resides in the row-2 below?
At now I use the following approach but it seems like ugly:

```
$cell.parent().parent().next().find('.cell-1');
```

Is there better approach?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $cell.closest('.row').next().find('.cell-1')
```

or

```
 $cell.parents('.row').next().find('.cell-1')
```